# Are the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ in a finite number?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $K$ be a compact set and consider $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$. It is easy to show that, if $n\geq 2$, the set $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ contains one (and only one) unbounded connected component. Could someone can help m to show that the remaining connected components of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ are in finite number? Alternatively, also some references will be well accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not true. For $r\in\mathbb{R}$ consider

$$S(r)=\big\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ \lVert v\rVert=r\big\}$$
$$K=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S(1/n)$$

For $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have that $K$ consists of nested circles converging to $0$.

$K$ is compact (as a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) but $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash K$ always has infinitely many connected components.

Note that $K$ itself is disconnected. But adding (path) connectedness requirement on $K$ doesn't change anything. We just have to modify our $S(r)$ so that these are nested spheres but all share the same single point, i.e. the $n$-dimensional [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\varphi:\overline{\Omega}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, if I take $K=\varphi(\partial\Omega)$, nothing change in your logic, isn't it?

Comment: Nope. You can take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n\backslash K$ with $K$ being the nested spheres (like in my answer). Then $\overline{\Omega}=\mathbb{R}^n$, $\partial\Omega=K$ and it still holds for the identity $\varphi(x)=x$.